# Having problems with Python rounding

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a python program and when I have a variable which is a float (3.14) it changes it to an integer (3). How can I prevent the variable changes from 3.14 to 3 and make it round to 4?

For example:

- 2.8458 rounds down to 2, but I want it to round up to 3
- 4.1 rounds down to 4, but I want it to round up to 5

Thanks for any help - it is much appreciated.

Comment: So you want to round up? Try `import math` and then `math.ceil(3.14)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ceil(ceiling)

```
import math
math.ceil(5.2)
6
```

Comment: ive used this command however how do i make it print the answer?

Comment: @PenroseCJ assign math.ceil() to a variable and use the print function

Comment: apple=(3.14)
import math
math.ceil(apple)
print (apple)                                This print 3.14